# Age of wonders 3 show direction the unit is facing in combat more clearly

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

is there a setting or a mod that shows clearly with an arrow or something in which direction the enemy units are facing? Maybe it's me but sometimes it's difficult to tell from the visuals alone the direction the unit is facing.